# C++ compiler that runs on windows and generates Linux code

Tags: c++, windows, linux, compiler-construction

I'm just curious if this is posible:
Is there C++ compiler that runs on windows and can generate Linux code?

Comment: `g++` installed in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) could probably do it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Cross-compiling is possible, yes. Another question is if there's an easily installable/configurable cross-compiler on windows. Why do you need this? Consider that (1) the usual procedure on linux is to compile from source (to the point where distributing binaries, except if tracked by a package manager, is frowned up) and (2) that if you really needed to do this, you can always set up a virtual machine with some linux and compile there.

Comment: Linux is a bit too generic a term. You need to specify the hardware and (Specific) OS (and its version) to get the correct X-Compiler. Its not trivial but doable.

Answer (score 6):

The [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/) cross compiler can do that.

See http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html.

Comment: Those are a bit outdated, but it's the right idea: just set up a cross-compiler where CBUILD=w32 (or cygwin) and CTARGET=linux.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely it's possible.  You need a compiler that can handle cross-compilations and then specify the target.  The key point is to get a compiler that's capable of creating the binary files in a manner required by the target system.  g++ would do just that for you.

I worked on a project where we used linux to create embedded arm executables using their C compiler, and then used scp to copy it over for testing.

Comment: Yes, developing for an embedded linux system using a windows host is probably the most common case where this is done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, but why bother? There is a risk that you will set it up incorrectly and get a binary which doesn't work correctly.

Plus also, you'll need vmware** installed so you can test the resulting binaries - you are going to run comprehensive tests, aren't you?

Simply set up another VM to do the building (because of course, you need to test that it will work on a machine without the build-tools installed).

** Other virtualisation platforms are available, this is not a commercial.

Comment: If you have development tools that only run on one platform but you want to produce binaries for another platform, it's definitely worth the bother.  I worked on a project where the development suite only ran on Windows but we targeted a set of other OSes, including Linux.  Cross compiling significantly cut down the time required to test changes.

Comment: Using a VM is by far the simplest and most robust solution, and allows testing on multiple Linux distributions.  Worth noting that because a VM can file share over a virtual network connection with the host, it is possible to use a combination of Windows and Linux tools for development and source code management

Comment: @Clifford - not necessarily.  If they have a lot invested in a comprehensive build system based in windows that is not portable, building a linux version there from their working copy of sources and then just pushing the binary onto a test box or vm may be preferable.  Especially as incremental builds off of network-shared source folders can easily go quite badly if the various machine's clocks aren't closely synchronized to the same network time source.

Comment: @Chris: I was not suggesting that it would necessarily be a seamless workflow, merely that if you want to write code in Visual Studio, but compile it on Linux for example, that is possible.  With respect to clock skew, the host and the VM would share the the same hardware clock at least, but that issue could be avoided also by using a version control system as an intermediate rather that using shared files directly.

Comment: Checking in and checking out the code is still a lot of overhead to build for the second system at all.  In many cases, when one isn't working on the machine specific parts of the code, if it worked on windows it will probably work on linux - the immediately interesting question after making some changes to generic parts of the program may be if the second compiler simply accepts it, not if the result runs (that will eventually have to be checked, but not as frequently).

Comment: Guys, I think it could go either way, although I would personally generally prefer a native compiler because it's "less surprising". This is particularly likely to be true for linking against lots of strange platform-libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are also libraries such as this one: http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/portability-libs/ that provide portability between platforms. For other ones I suggest looking for abstraction libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you have recent enough CPU you should get [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and just install [kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) or any other distro, while it might sound complicated it will be easier to test the binaries and debug them.